# Why registration.php added in magento-2.0.0-RC?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, component

Recently `magento-2.0.0-RC` was launched and they added `registration.php` in every module root folder? So I just want to know is there any reason for that?

Can someone put light on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`registration.php` is kind of the entry point of your module. It's the equivalent of `app/etc/modules/[Namespace]_[Module].xml` from Magento 1.
But now, is part of the module itself.
it allows you to create modules in the `app/code` folder and in the `vendor` folder as well.
No matter where you add it, this file will be picked up by Magento and your module will be taken into consideration.

Comment: Where you add it means I can place this file anywhere like block,model or controller directory or any other directory ? @Marius

Comment: And is there any reason for that because config.php is already there @Marius

Comment: in `config.php` only the module names appear and their status (enabled/disabled). There is no path to the module. Like I said in the answer, `registration.php` allows you to have modules outside `app/code`

Comment: See this for more details: https://maxyek.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/building-magento-2-extension-lets-begin/

Comment: @Marius : So the module should not work without registration.php right?

Comment: @Sukeshini. Right.

Answer (score 1):

i noticed two thing was changed  from Magento ver. 1.0.0-beta (Oct) to Magento ver. 2.0.0-rc2 
1. added new file in root folder of module called registration.php
ex:-app\code\Sugarcode\Test\registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sugarcode_Test',
    __DIR__
);
```

2. event.xml was changed 
   previous we are mention method name in observer tag in event.xml now method was removed juts you need to mention only instance that is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="sales_order_grid_collection_load_before">
            <observer name="sales_order_grid_test" instance="Sugarcode\Test\Observer\Addtest" />
        </event>

    </config>
```

and in /ModuleName/Observer folder you need to create a file with function

```
public function execute()
```

that is

```
<?php

namespace Sugarcode\Test\Observer;

class Addtest
{


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $obj=$observer->getEvent()->getOrderGridCollection();
        $obj->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['testt' => 'testtable'],
            "(main_table.entity_id = testt.id)",
            [
                'testt.title as title'
            ]
        );
        //$this->printlogquery(true); 
        //return $obj;
    }
}
```