# Module not working after namespace magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, custom-block

I used this module

`https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-additional-shipping-block`

to add a custom block to the shipment method, when I moved it to another namespace , it does not work any more . It is enabled but the custom block does not show , I changed the namespace "SR" to in all files, cleaned cache, upgraded .. any solutions ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you change the registration.php 
(https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-additional-shipping-block/blob/master/SR/AdditionalShippingBlock/registration.php)

If not - change it to yours namespace 
Of course you need to change the namespace to your name after you moved it

please go for your root magento project folder and do :

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

for more information:
[Why registration.php added in magento-2.0.0-RC?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89510/why-registration-php-added-in-magento-2-0-0-rc)

if its on the block you need to define it on the xml 
https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-additional-shipping-block/blob/master/SR/AdditionalShippingBlock/etc/frontend/di.xml

after this do

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

for more information:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html

by the way - next time put some code of your on by git or whatever to get some clues because i need to guess the problem if you talk about the di.xml or module.xml

anyway - please keep me update.

In general you need to change at least 5-6 files and replace with your namespace